# Return a IQueryable from join with a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

In order to avoid gaps in a report a do a join with a data range.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<ReportDTO>> JoinDateRangeAsync( DashboardFilter filter, IQueryable<ReportDTO> queryable ) {

            if (filter is null)
                return null;

            if (queryable is null)
                return null;

            var dateRange = DateHelpers.GetDatesRanges( await this.GetFromDateFromDashbordFilterAsync( filter ), GetToDateFromDashbordFilter( filter ) );
            return
                from d in dateRange
                join r in queryable on new { x = (short)d.DayOfYear, y = (short)d.Year } equals new { x = r.DayOfYear, y = r.Year} into dr
                from r in dr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new ReportDTO( d, r );
        }
```

My Helper function

```
        public static DateTime[] GetDatesRanges( DateTime from, DateTime to ) {
            return Enumerable
                .Range( 0, 1 + to.Subtract( from ).Days )
                .Select( offset => from.AddDays( offset ) )
                .ToArray();
        }
```

The problem that in this way a have to return a IEnumerable. For performance reason, Is it possible to return a object of type IQueryable?

Comment: Move it to the database.

Comment: @Gserg, Thanks for the clue. That was my initial idea. I found simpler the implementation with EF, I didn' suspect to face up to this issue. For the DB implementation I should have a table that contains all days. Which is the best practice?

Comment: Generate the date list in the DB, e.g. from a table-valued function.